# Como saber se uma chave no sql server é identity

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Como saber se uma chave no sql server é identity? Como eu faço para descobrir? A versão é 2014.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT is_identity 
FROM sys.columns 
WHERE object_id = object_id('Nome_da_sua_tabela') 
AND name = 'Nome_da_sua_coluna'
```

Vai retornar 1 se a coluna for identity

Answer (score 2):

Complementando a resposta do @Artur, caso queira uma relação (tabela/coluna) de todas as chaves identitys de uma determinada base de dados:

```
select o.name, c.name
from sys.objects o inner join sys.columns c on o.object_id = c.object_id
where c.is_identity = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o [COLUMNPROPERTY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms174968.aspx) para isso.

```
select columnproperty(object_id('NomeTabela'),'NomeColuna','IsIdentity')
```

Desta forma retornará uma das opções:

- 1 = TRUE
- 0 = FALSE
- NULL = A entrada não é válida.